# I need a proxy app that isn't tor!

Tags: software-recommendation, internet, proxy

Hi my internet has censored by devil isp, I use **freegate.tv** and **psiphone** when I used Windows before Ubuntu. Both are great and free.
Tor works very lazy and slow because my internet is very poor (**512 kb**) so I need a free app to pass censorship but not Tor.

Do you know another free app?

Comment: The Best Proxy is Very Fast : http://fast-ip.com/

Answer (score 0):

Where are you located?  If your in the US, instructions are below, otherwise you might need a UK VPN or one for your country.

I use the below built into Ubuntu, no third party software required but note that a VPN is not the same as a proxy though it will get around the blocking.  If you wish to use a proxy still, there are plenty of web proxies available but I think a lot of ISP's that block certain sites, would also block popular web proxies and they are often very slow.
http://strongvpn.com/difference_between_proxy_and_vpn.shtml

It is a US VPN and it should get you around your ISP issues.  There are others I'm sure but this is the one I've been using with success.
http://usafreevpn.com/

All you have to do is click on the wireless icon on the top right in Ubuntu, hover over VPN Connections and then click configure VPN.

Click add and on the VPN tab, fill in the details from the website above.

Give the connection a name at the top and click OK.

Then click on the wireless icon again and click VPN connections and click the name you gave it above.

Ubuntu will try to connect and will inform you if it does connect.  You disconnect the same way when your done.